# Replace default og:image tag YOAST

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm trying to replace the default image picked by yoast (featured image) with a custom with the relative og:image:width and og:image:height, but seems a mission impossible!

I tryed with this:

```
function my_own_og_function() {
    $my_image_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.net/wp-content/uploads/TEST-A.jpg';
    $GLOBALS['wpseo_og']->image( $my_image_url ); // This will echo out the og tag in line with other WPSEO og tags
}
add_action( 'wpseo_opengraph', 'my_own_og_function', 29 );
```

But yes, the image is replaced, only is without og:image:width and og:image:height

So i'm wondering, is there away to make it possible? Please, i need your help to make this, i have spent all the night trying to achive what i'm looking for... Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wpseo_opengraph_image_size` filter. You can use any WP image size (default ones like `medium` or ones added by themes and plugins which will be specific to your site) in the first line:

```
// set 'medium' to whichever size you need
$size = 'medium';
// the size is then applied in this filter
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image_size', create_function("$size", 'return "opengraph";'));
```

Comment: But in wordpress settings i have set all thumb size to "0", because i don't want any cropped image...
In your way can i set manually width and height? Or even with getimagesize() ?

Comment: <b>Deprecated</b>:  Function create_function() is deprecated in...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/* Yoast Seo Imagen Medium para compartir */
function sc_opengraph_image_size($size="medium") {
    return "medium";
}
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image_size','sc_opengraph_image_size',10,1);
```